# Making images show up globally in all pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm using Paperclip + AWS S3 + Imagemagick for the image. It works completely fine in the www.example.com/users with the tag (maybe because I put the Paperclip model and controller stuff in there?)

```
<%= image_tag user.avatar.url(:small)%>
```

but, the same code won't show up in a different page such as www.example.com/conversations.

I'm getting an error saying:

```
NameError in Conversations#show
undefined local variable or method `user' for #<#<Class:0x007f9c10d25010>:0x007f9c10c17ce0>
```

Comment: **undefined local variable or method 'user'** - This error specifies that you have not defined `user` in your `ConversationsController` `show` action. You should be posting the relevant  `ConversationsController` code.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using devise for authentication then you should do:

```
<%= image_tag current_user.avatar.url(:small)%>
```

if you are using your own authentication then you should do something like in your controllers:

```
before_action: set_user
def set_user
  @user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) # Or your criteria to set user
end
```

in html.erb file or probably in your layout file

```
<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:small) %>
```

If I was doing this then I would have done like this.

1. Create partial in *layouts/shared/_avatar.html.erb* with following code.

`<%= image_tag user.avatar.url(:small) %>`

2. Add `befor_action: set_user` and `set_user` method in controller method like I said.
3. render partial (created in Step 1) in layout or whenever you require to show user avatar image by passing locals to partial.

`<%= render "layouts/shared/avatar", user: @user %>`

Comment: <%= image_tag current_user.avatar.url(:small)%>
Would only show the picture of the current user, but not the person he's talking to, right?

Comment: I figured it out! The problem was that I had a different name set for the users in my conversations controller. All I had to do was change <%= image_tag user.avatar.url(:small)%> to <%= image_tag participant.avatar.url(:small)%>

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had a different name set for the users in my conversations controller. 
All I had to do was change

```
<%= image_tag user.avatar.url(:small)%>
```

to

```
<%= image_tag participant.avatar.url(:small)%>
```